# Why method with an await Task.Delay inside an if statement is not working in C#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm sorry if the tittle is a bit confusing.

I have an array-sorting webapp in Blazor.

This is the important piece of code:

```
<MudButton OnClick="Sort" Disabled="Sorting" Variant="Variant.Outlined" >Sort</MudButton>
<MudButton OnClick="Accelerate" Disabled="@(!Sorting)" Variant="Variant.Outlined">Finish</MudButton>

@code{
    public bool Sorting { get; set; } = false;
    public bool Accelerating { get; set; } = default!;

    public void Sort()
    {
        Sorting = true;
        Bubble();
    }

    public void Accelerate()
    {
        Accelerating = true;
    }


    public async void Bubble()
    {
        while (!IsSorted(List))
        {
        //algorithm
            StateHasChanged();
            if (!Accelerating)
            {
                await Task.Delay((Speed - MAX_SPEED) * -1 == 0 ? 1 : (Speed - MAX_SPEED) * -1);
            }
        }
        Sorting = false;
        Accelerating = false;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

The sorting part works just fine.
When I click the Accelerate button the await Task.Delay should be skipped.
But when I do, the whole application freezes like this:

[image]

[image]

It won't respond. Nothing in console.

Where is the problem? Thanks

Comment: What are the vallues of `Speed` and `MAX_SPEED`.  If `MAX_SPEED` is much larger than `Speed` then it's going to delay for a long time.

Comment: But why? The idea is to skip that Delay with the 'if'.
Speed and MAX_SPEED are both 200.

Comment: Are you sure they're both 200? If `Speed - MAX_SPEED` comes out to `-1`, then `Task.Delay()` will [wait forever](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=net-7.0#:~:text=Int32-,The%20number%20of%20milliseconds%20to%20wait%20before%20completing%20the%20returned%20task%2C%20or%20%2D1%20to%20wait%20indefinitely.,-Returns).

Comment: And what's the point of the `* -1`? The only way that `(Speed - MAX_SPEED) * -1` would equal `0` is if `Speed - MAX_SPEED` equals `0`. The `* -1` is redundant.

Comment: Yes, the initial values are 200. I'm not touching the sliders.

Comment: The app is frozen b/c of a multithreading issue. The While loop is on thread 1, while the event is on thread 2. Hackish, but make the property volatile: `public volatile bool Accelerating`

Comment: I understand, 'volatile' is not solving the issue though.

Comment: Then validate the delay is being toggled with a longer delay. Just replace all that nonsense in the delay with `await Task.Delay(3000)` - toggling should now be clear the delay is being skipped or not.

Comment: Same thing. The 3s delay works but the app freezes when I click the accelerate button.

Comment: Without that the UI wont update if I change some data. (the array in this case)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something here, there's not enough information to answer this question.  What is `!IsSorted(list).  I see a mention above of "sliders".  What are they doing?  Where is speed being set and when?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that when `Accelerating` becomes `true`, your CPU usage skyrockets.

Awaiting the delay gives the UI a chance to respond to user input, but without it, it can't. Once `Accelerating` becomes `true`, you end up in an infinite loop that occupies the UI thread entirely, and all user input gets put in a queue waiting for the UI thread to be freed, which never happens.

Comment: Yes, I agree with this answer. When Accelerating is `false` its running a tight loop on UI thread, not allowing any windowing events to be processed before the loop is over.  Hence UI will appear frozen until then.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
Accelerating = false;
```

Will flip Accelerating to false the 2nd time you click the button, thus opening things up for Task.Delay to run.

Comment: Without that line the result is the same.